Python: Reading Stock Data out of a Chart
I am trying to scrape stock data from a stock exchange website, e.g.
https://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/aktie/vonovia-se
Instead of reading the values (low/high/last) from a given table, I wonder if there is a way to read the data directly from the chart. When hoovering over the chart, the daily values are indicated.
This is the HTML code. I highlighted the line which creates the chart
<canvas style="....> 
Does anyone figure out where the stock data is coming from? And how I can scrape it?
https://www.boerse-frankfurt.de/aktie/vonovia-se

Although you can probably figure out a way to obtain the data eventually, it seems to be a lot easier to just use the API they provide, instead of trying to scrape it from a very involved UI? https://console.developer.deutsche-boerse.com/apis
